# Save pdf with overprint simulated

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting, overprint

Is there anyway I can generate a version of a pdf which shows on screen, simulated overprint. I essentially want to send my client there artwork back showing the overprint simulated. I don’t want them to have to use acrobat and enable the overprint preview. We usually place there artwork within a indesign template (using a script) and save this so anything that could be incorporated into this process would be helpful.

Comment: Is the overprint on black only? or they are two different Pantone colors.

Comment: It could be on any colour, stroke or fill. We receive a lot of files from designers who have used logos or elements within the artwork which they’ve copied so on most occasions they aren’t aware they’ve done it.

Comment: Export as jpg maybe?

Comment: Screen shot of the artwork with overprint preview on in Acrobat or a preflight program?

Comment: This works for exporting as jpeg but ideally need the pdf.  Thanks for this though, it wasn't something I'd considered.  I currently use pitstop to identify and fix but a screen grab or outputting as a jpeg isn't quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: I was hoping there might be a setting when saving the pdf from indesign which allows you to simulate it.  Perhaps a certain pdf standard or something but I'm not that well versed on the specifics of this.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to find a way around this. When I save from InDesign I have a *PDF Preset* which uses the PDF/X-4:2010 *Standard*.

This automatically enables *Simulate Overprinting* when the PDF is opened in Adobe Acrobat.

The PDF also gets an *Output Intent* so Acrobat automatically can choose the right *Simulation Profile*.

Comment: Hi and welcome to GDSE! I took the liberty to edit your answer. Added a bit of formatting and fixed some typos. I'm italicizing terms from Adobe programs so they are easier to spot, that's just my preference. I also tried to make it clear that only Adobe Acrobat can be trusted to display the PDF like you intent. Feel free to revert the edits if you disagree.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to correct this. Would you be willing to expand on this for me and explain the possible consequences of converting a pdf to a different standard. Could this change anything which would affect the appearance of the file on screen? Anything you could help with my understanding would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like something you should ask as a new question. I honestly can't answer right now without googling. Even though I'm in the print business I seldom meet demands for a standard. But I know that, as you can see for yourself, all other standards than PDF/X-4:2010 forces *Compatibility* to be set to *Acrobat 4 (PDF 1.3)* which, among other things, splits images into tiles, flattens transparency and doesn't look too good on screen.